# Error in tf.contrib.learn Quickstart, no attribute named load_csv

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, tensorflow, osx-elcapitan

I am getting started in tensorflow on OSX and installed the lasted version following the guidelines for a pip installation using:

```
echo $TF_BINARY_URL
https://storage.googleapis.com/tensorflow/mac/cpu/tensorflow-0.11.0rc0-py2-none-any.whl
```

Quick overview:

OS: OS X El Capitan version 10.11.6 (15G31)

Python: Python 2.7.12_1 installed with `brew install python`

TensorFlow: 0.11.0rc0 from `import tensorflow as tf; print(tf.__version__)`

I can run TensorFlow using:

```
python
>>> import tensorflow as tf
>>> hello = tf.constant('Hello, TensorFlow!')
>>> sess = tf.Session()
>>> print(sess.run(hello))
>>> Hello, TensorFlow!
```

So TensorFlow is installed and running the basic commands.

But when I run the code for tf.contrib.learn Quickstart from here:
https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/tflearn/index.html

I get the following issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tf_learn_quickstart.py", line 13, in <module>
    training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'load_csv'
```

I can't figure out what went wrong as everything else seems to be working fine. Any ideas what is wrong?

Answer (score 2):

This function has been deprecated: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/commit/2d4267507e312007a062a90df37997bca8019cfb

And the tutorial seems not up to date. I believe you can simply replace load_csv with load_csv_with_header to get it work.

Comment: Thank you. I replaced load_csv with load_csv_with_headers, and added the extra argument for the feature_dtype=np.float32.

Comment: @IsaacNoble It is `features_dtype`.  From [base.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/contrib/learn/python/learn/datasets/base.py) : `load_csv_with_header(filename, target_dtype, features_dtype, target_column=-1)`

Answer (score 1):

The quick fix for people here wanting to run the tutorial.

Replace

```
# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
                                                       target_dtype=np.int)
test_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv(filename=IRIS_TEST,
                                                   target_dtype=np.int)
```

with

```
# Load datasets.
training_set = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TRAINING,
                                                                  target_dtype=np.int,
                                                                  features_dtype=np.float32,
                                                                  target_column=-1)
test_set     = tf.contrib.learn.datasets.base.load_csv_with_header(filename=IRIS_TEST,
                                                                  target_dtype=np.int,
                                                                  features_dtype=np.float32,
                                                                  target_column=-1)
```